# How to use use same configuration between .NET Framework, .NET Standard, and .NET Core project?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-standard

Since the `ConfigurationManager` doesn't exist in .NET Standard, what is the best way to retrieve application settings for the executing assembly, whether it be a `web.config` or an `appSettings.{env}.json`, within a .NET standard class library?

We have three projects:

- ASP.NET Core Web App (1.1)
- ASP.NET Web App (4.6.1 )
- .NET Standard Class Library (1.4) -> Referenced by both projects

In the .NET Standard class lib, we have a URL which needs to change based on the environment it's deployed to.

This is fine for the .NET Core app, we simply add the URLs to the appropriate `appSettings.{env}.json` file, add the appropriate values to the DI container, then use the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` library to retrieve the configuration.

However, we also need to call the library from our .NET Framework 4.6.1 application, but since there is no method (at least none that I could find) to retrieve the values from a `web.config` file, we don't have a good way to set the URL within the class library.

We've gotten around this for now by making the URL variable static and setting its value from within the `Application_Start()` method of each .NET Framework project we reference it from, we determine which environment it is via an appSetting key we added to each web.config, then manually set the URL based on the environment.

Is there a more robust way to handle retrieving appSettings values from both a .NET Core and .NET Framework application within a .NET Standard class library?
Preferably where we can set the value solely within the class library.

Comment: Thanks for the random down-vote on a completely legitimate question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the value from configuration before calling your library, and pass it by parameter, either into a method or constructor.

In general, library code shouldn't depend on side effects from the configuration of its host environment.  Doing so makes it very difficult to reuse code, or to test effectively.

Comment: That's already how we're doing it - in the `Global.asax.cs`, we call a `SetClientUrl(string clientApiUrl)` method based on the configuration in each .NET Framework project that uses it. I was hoping there might be a more scalable way. Our library is generated based on a Swagger API and requires a different IP Address depending on which server it's deployed to so we don't really have a choice. If all projects were .NET Core or all projects were .NET Framework, this would be totally possible so I assumed there would be some way to accomplish this in .NET Standard.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing the right thing then, though I'd think about if there's a way to enforce usage.  For example, via a constructor parameter.  Hard to say without specifics.  (wasn't my downvote btw, I think this is a good question.)

Comment: I figured it wasn't you; Typically, the ones who down-vote don't also take the time to answer the question as well :) Ok - then it seems it isn't currently possible to achieve retrieving appSettings from both a `web.config` and `appSettings.json` in a .NET standard project. Thanks for your response.